# Parsing JSONP with AFNetworking/JSONKit

Tags: objective-c, jsonp, afnetworking

I need help parsing the below url:

I know how to do this if the format had been JSON, but its in the format JSONP.

http://sg.media-imdb.com/suggests/h/hello.json

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSONP is just JSON wrapped in a function call: `callback(JSON_GOES_HERE)`. So just find outermost parentheses, then proceed to parse as JSON whatever is inside them.