# get JSON from JSONP response

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, jsonp

I'm trying to get json from url which return JSONP response like this :

> A_string_Blalblalbla(**JSON_Content**)

So I've tried to serialize my response but I get :

> JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.

And here's my code :

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

//manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
    [manager GET:@"http://miraath.ddns.net:2199/external/rpc.php?callback=jsonp1436888493343&_=1436888517235&m=streaminfo.get&username=miraath1&charset=&mountpoint=&rid=miraath1" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Also I tried to change acceptable content to text :

```
 manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"];
```

But I get this error :

> NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/javascript

So any help over here how to extract the json from response

Comment: A JSONP response is JavaScript, not JSON, and so a JSON parser won't be able to parse it. However, in many cases you can get away with trimming everything before (and including) the first `(` and everything after (and including) the last `)`. If everything between the parentheses is valid JSON, your JSON parser won't have any trouble with it.

Comment: Yeah because this api was built for web at te begining. So how to get this response as string !!? So after that i can't trim it

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017306/parsing-jsonp-with-afnetworking-jsonkit?s=1|1.9139

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah I've tried to set acceptableContentTypes to plain text so I can then read it as string but it didn't work, so how to get this reponse as text, string, so then I can work on it and extract the json string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `callback` variable from the URI string gets you a clean JSON response: http://miraath.ddns.net:2199/external/rpc.php?_=1436888517235&m=streaminfo.get&username=miraath1&charset=&mountpoint=&rid=miraath1

```
{"type":"result","rid":"miraath1","data":[{"title":"Miraath","song":"\u0642\u0631\u0627\u0621\u0629 \u0641\u062a\u0627\u0648\u0649 \u0641\u064a \u0623\u062d\u0643\u0627\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0635\u064a\u0627\u0645 - \u0627\u0644\u0634\u064a\u062e \u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f \u0628\u0646 \u0635\u0627\u0644\u062d \u0627\u0644\u0639\u062b\u064a\u0645\u064a\u0646","track":{"artist":"\u0642\u0631\u0627\u0621\u0629 \u0641\u062a\u0627\u0648\u0649 \u0641\u064a \u0623\u062d\u0643\u0627\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0635\u064a\u0627\u0645","title":"\u0627\u0644\u0634\u064a\u062e \u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f \u0628\u0646 \u0635\u0627\u0644\u062d \u0627\u0644\u0639\u062b\u064a\u0645\u064a\u0646","album":"","royaltytrackid":0,"imageurl":"http:\/\/miraath.ddns.net:2197\/static\/miraath1\/covers\/nocover.png"},"bitrate":"32 Kbps","server":"Online","autodj":"Offline","source":"Yes","offline":false,"summary":"<a href=\"http:\/\/miraath.ddns.net:2199\/tunein\/-stream\/miraath1.pls\">Miraath - \u0642\u0631\u0627\u0621\u0629 \u0641\u062a\u0627\u0648\u0649 \u0641\u064a \u0623\u062d\u0643\u0627\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0635\u064a\u0627\u0645 - \u0627\u0644\u0634\u064a\u062e \u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f \u0628\u0646 \u0635\u0627\u0644\u062d \u0627\u0644\u0639\u062b\u064a\u0645\u064a\u0646<\/a>","listeners":113,"maxlisteners":1000,"reseller":0,"serverstate":true,"sourcestate":false,"sourceconn":true,"date":"Jul 14, 2015","time":"08:59 PM","rawmeta":"\u0642\u0631\u0627\u0621\u0629 \u0641\u062a\u0627\u0648\u0649 \u0641\u064a \u0623\u062d\u0643\u0627\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0635\u064a\u0627\u0645 - \u0627\u0644\u0634\u064a\u062e \u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f \u0628\u0646 \u0635\u0627\u0644\u062d \u0627\u0644\u0639\u062b\u064a\u0645\u064a\u0646","mountpoint":"\/stream","tuneinurl":"http:\/\/151.80.100.177:7000\/stream","tuneinformat":"mp3","webplayer":"jplayer","servertype":"IceCast","url":"http:\/\/miraath.ddns.net:2199\/"}]}
```

Comment: Thank's that work's like charms, so removing the callback will always work, convert jsonP to json ?

Comment: Hard to say. In most cases, yes. It is possible that a developer might design an API that always requires a callback for a JSON response, but all good developers will accommodate both options.